# dd/mm automatically got changed to mm/dd

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

I coded something using Date statement in Access VBA. It was working fine until the start of this month, but now I am seeing that the Date has automatically changed the format from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `mm/dd/yyyy`. Has anyone else encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default Access SQL date format, regardless of locale, is mm/dd/yyyy. If you use an invalid date format, it will 'helpfully' try to convert that to a valid date for you.

So, if you use '30/09/2008', it will recognize you're using dd/mm/yyyy, and convert it appropriately. However, a value like '10/01/2008' is a valid mm/dd/yyyy value to begin with, so it will not be converted, and stored incorrectly in case you actually meant dd/mm/yyyy....

The solution is to always convert your date values to a mm/dd/yyyy string prior to using them in Access SQL statements. You have to be a bit careful here, as using VBA date format masks may not work entirely as you'd expect on non-US locales (e.g. 'helpfully' interpreting "mm/dd/yyyy" as "the localized short date format"), so please test carefully using your particular Access/VBA version.

Comment: Thanks @mdb, you are right. And I am coding in non-US locale.

Comment: Access doesn't have a SQL version, but Jet does, so what you mean is "the default Jet SQL date format...."

Comment: Another solution is to use a non-ambiguous date format, such as yyyy/mm/dd or dd-mmm-yyyy.

Comment: I would also go with a year, month, day format as the safest.

Answer (score 3):

Access requires a date to be unambiguous. It is generally recommended that you use yyyy/mm/dd, regardless of locale. For example:

```
strSQL="SELECT SomeDate FROM tblT WHERE SomeDate=#" & Format(DateVar, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
stLinkCriteria = "[ProjectDate] Between #" & Format(CDate(Me![txtDateFrom]), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & Format(CDate(Me![txtDateTo]), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
sentenciaSQL = "UPDATE Numeraciones " & _
"SET Valor = " & Valor & ", " & _
"Fecha = #" & **Format(fecha,"mm/dd/yyyy HH:nn:ss") & "#, " &** _
"Id_Usuario = " & Id_Usuario & _
" WHERE Nombre = '" & Nombre & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been very successful using the datevalue() function.  When getting dates from unbound controls it seems to be clever enough to interpret the format "dd/mm/yyyy" correctly.  Thus, a Jet SQL query like

`"Select * from DateTable where StartDate = datevalue(" & me!TxtStartDate & ");"`

seems to work every time.

Comment: That won't be as reliable as DateSerial(Year(Me!TxtStartDate), Month(Me!TxtStartDate), Day(Me!TxtStartDate)).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing same issue while trying to build a SQL string through VBA.
My locale settings use dd/mm/yyyy and I was trying to put into SQL statement data taken from an unbound textbox in a form.
The issue was due to the fact I was declaring, let's say, varMyDate as "date" type, so the engine reverted the format back even after the format.
Since you are really building a string the logical and proper data type  is "string", and that solved the problem.